# Serve an external full webpage trough Flask

Tags: python, html, static, web

I'm trying to do the following:

Having a file structure like the following:

```
/app
    /static
        /start
            /css
            /js
            - index.html
    /templates
```

Id like to know how I can serve this index.html and make this load its CSS and JS without using url_for('static', filename='') or other kind of serving trough Flask.

Basically, I want to put `http://local.com/start` and trough Flask serve index.html which will load its own css and js like `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

I tried `send_from_directory('/static/start', "index.html")` and `app.send_static_file('index.html')` but they don't work.

I also tried `current_app.send_static_file('start/index.html')` but this only serves the html. It doesn't make the index.html load its own CSS and JS.

I got the information from these links

[How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

[python flask - serving static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883874/python-flask-serving-static-files)

[Flask: How to serve static html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578330/flask-how-to-serve-static-html)

They don't do what I want (or maybe I'm doing it wrong).

Thanks in advance, if there is more info needed just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a regular html file as a jinja template.  Just call `render` without any parameters.