# Serving static html file from another directory from flask restful endpoint

Tags: python, flask

I have a toy REST application which is structured in a following way:

```
 - client/
   - css/
   - js/
   - index.html
 - server/
   - app.py
   ... some other files  which I use in app.py
```

`app.py` is a flask restful endpoint which looks like this:

```
app = flask.Flask('some-name')

# a lot of API end points, which look in this way
@app.route('/api/something', methods=['GET'])
def func_1():
    ...
```

and now I want to serve my static index html. So after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883874/python-flask-serving-static-files) and [this](http://codepen.io/asommer70/blog/serving-a-static-directory-with-flask), I thought that I would be able to serve it easily by adding the following lines:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    # but neither with this line
    return app.send_static_file('../client/index.html')
    # nor with this
    return flask.render_template(flask.url_for('static', filename='../client/index.html'))
```

I can not see my html file (logs tell me: `127.0.0.1 - - [some day] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -`). I know that I can move index.html in the server folder but is there a way to serve it from where it is right now?

**P.S.** when I added `app._static_folder = "../client/"` and changed my home function to `return app.send_static_file('index.html')` I finally started to receive my html file, but all the css/js file that are inside html are returned with 404.

Comment: Flask can be configured to serve files on special "static" endpoint. Take a look at this document. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/

Comment: And of corse, urls in index.html should be set correctly. That means, you need to used "static" endpoint ( example.com/static/main.css )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When creating flask app, configure *static_folder* to your *client* folder.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="client")
```

Then you can access js and css on url `http://localhost:5000/static/css/main.css`

About your initial question. You can serve static html pages with flask like this:

```
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def serve_page(path):
    return send_from_directory('client', path)
```

Comment: or `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', static_url_path='')` if you want to avoid the 'static' in the url.