# Serving a Single index.html With Flask from a Different Directory

Tags: python, flask

I currently have a folder structure like so:

```
/
--client
----dist
------index.html
------index.js
--server
----server.py
```

The `index.js` in `dist/` serves a react application. My `server.py` looks like this:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return send_from_directory('../client/dist/', 'index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This doesn't work unfortunately and I get a `Failed to load resource`. I looked at several posts on SO and beyond regarding this. Most of them are very old (and perhaps outdated), and all of them usually have a different folder structure where the `index.html` file is served from a `static` folder within `server/` or something similar.

I really just want to do what I imagine should be an easy task: When `localhost:5000` is visited, Flask serves `../client/dist/index.html` and from there React takes over and does its thing.

I would be very grateful if someone can provide me a minimal/clean way of achieving thing.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I was somewhat wrong. I thought the question wasn't a repost but after some more searching I found another StackOverflow question very similar to mine:

[Serving static html file from another directory from flask restful endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951256/serving-static-html-file-from-another-directory-from-flask-restful-endpoint)

Putting together a couple of answers from there and elsewhere, I have a minimal working solution:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../client/dist')

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I now visit `localhost:5000` I get the contents of `index.html`.